# How to get the the Opportunity Record Type name from the Opportunity line items

Tags: trigger

I want to get the recordtype name and check if equal to "Training" from the Opportunitylineitem

```
List<OpportunityLineItem> Ren = [Select OpportunityId,  opportunity.RecordType.DeveloperName 
from OpportunityLineItem
where opportunityid = '0063F000001uIsS'];
```

DeveloperName is not showing in the apex code, only 
DEBUG|(OpportunityLineItem:{OpportunityId=0063F000001uIsSQAU, Id=00k3F000003KS9QQAW}

and also how can i get the Training Record NAme so that I could use it on Succeeding process.

if (ren.recordname = 'Training')
 { do something....}

also want to check first of list is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you cannot see it in a list (as I have tried it also), but if you target the field specifically, it will show. You can see it in workbench though.

```
for(OpportunityLineItem Ren : [Select OpportunityId,Opportunity.RecordType.DeveloperName 
from OpportunityLineItem ]){
    system.debug('recordTypeName : '+Ren.Opportunity.RecordType.DeveloperName); 
    if(Ren.Opportunity.RecordType.DeveloperName == 'Training'){
        //do something
    }
}
```